# Server side handler for JSNLog

Tags: winston, jsnlog

I have requirement to store client side logs to server side file system. I see JSNlog Ajax appender post JSON data.
Is there a server side handler to write JSON log data to file system someone has already written? I don't use nodejs currently but if there is async winston handler for this, that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

I am the author of JSNLog.

There already is a server side handler, called jsnlog-nodejs. This is an NPM package.

You said you do not use NodeJs, so I'm not sure what server side technology you use. In addition to NodeJs, there is also a JSNLog server side endpoint for .Net (on jsnlog.com).

If you decide to write your own server side endpoint, the structure of the messages sent by JSNLog is here:
http://js.jsnlog.com/Documentation/DownloadInstall

About Winston, JSNLog supports this out of the box. You will have seen that JSNLog uses appenders. Any Winston transport can be used as an appender. See:
http://nodejs.jsnlog.com/Documentation/HowTo/LogToDb

More info if you do use NodeJs on the server:
http://nodejs.jsnlog.com/Documentation/DownloadInstall